# Text Spills out of div on browser resize?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a div I want to hold my text, but when I zoom the window out the text breaks up and spills out the bottom. This seems to only be an issue in chrome, and I was hoping someone could help me.

```
.about{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    max-height: 226px;
    max-width: 515px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class=about>
    <h3>Welcome:</h3>
    <p> All my Text goes here that keeps spilling out.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want it to do. you have a max height. overflow scroll or overflow hidden should change that

Comment: It happens some time due to property of <p> tag, (padding and margin)

The working seems normal to me in my PC in chrome, below the welcome and on re-size of browser it wraps in the div!!

I think you need to be more specific with .about{text-align:inline.}

Comment: Provide a demo: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), etc.

Answer (score 1):

that's an expected behavior. When you Zoom- in, you are actually increasing the pixel size i.e. reducing the resolution, so everything appears big, i.e now your elements with same pixel width and height, cover more space. As you increase the zoom level to be high enough that, your content(i.e. text) cannot be accommodated in a single row, it breaks down to the next row. so that's as per expectations.

As per practices, you should give your div a width and text a font-size, that it can be accommodated in wide range of resolutions(low or high).

Though if you want the text to remain horizontal, you can give a static width to its container, that way when you zoom-in, a horizontal scroll would appear, as  the div is a block element.

so do either of these -

- don't make your app compatible for infinite zoom, it should be for a given range, best way to test that out is making it compatible in all the resolutions available on your machine.
- in order to achieve above, try to give width in percentage, so that in-appropriate horizontal scrolls don't appear at different resolutions
- if the width is always going to be lower than 500px, then give it a static width, as that width can be accommodated on most of the screens.

Answer (score 1):

Try resizing EVERYTHING with ems. I mean, everything from your fonts to your borders, margins, etc. It will be a nice responsive design.

ALSO, try setting a height. For starters, begin with 600 px if you insist on staying with pixels, or try 200 ems.

Comment: Try `rem`. I prefer it over `em`

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to break your line you can use `white-space` property set to `nowrap`

```
.about{

white-space:nowrap; 

}
```

so your text not break

and set your max-width it also can be a problam

Answer (score 0):

only add width:515px with your class instead of max-width
here you go

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .about{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    max-height: 226px;
    width:515px;
    //max-width: 515px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
     <div class=about>
        <h3>Welcome:</h3>
        <p> All my Text goes here that keeps spilling out.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```